# MySQL custom Timestamp value

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I'm having some troubles dealing with **Timestamp** data type in MySQL.

I'm saving simple records in my database using a simple DB structure, like:

```
ID   int
Name varchar
Date timestamp
Text varchar
```

And then retrieve them with something like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-06-30'
```

Everything works fine if I store records letting MySQL fill the Date field with the actual timestamp, for example: `2013-10-04 22:40:02` which means I don't add any value to the `Date` field in my `INSERT` query.

But I need to be able to add the date by my self since my application needs to store the date from where the application started, and not the date and time in which the query was sent to the database.
So what I do is I create the same date/time format my `Date` field uses which is `2013-10-04 22:40:02` and then do a simply insert:

```sql
INSERT INTO table (Name, Date, Text)
VALUES ('Peter', '2013-10-04 22:40:02', 'Hello...')
```

Now, doing it this way I'm unable to bring any result by date using a select query like this one:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-11-30'
```

Even if I try to sort results by Date using PHPMyAdmin interface, all the records that contain manually added dates disappear. If I sort them by ID, they re-appear. I checked and the dates and formats are correct. So I have no idea what the problem could be. I'm new at MySQL by the way.

Hope you can give me a hand. Thanks!

Comment: will this work: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Date BETWEEN '2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-11-30 23:59:59'` ?

Comment: @iamde_coder thanks for your suggestion, I tried it but no luck, it only brings the results with Date added automatically

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I found the problem and it has nothing to do with PHP and MySQL, the problem is that I generate the date with JavaScript, and it's giving the wrong month.. :/

Thanks to everyone anyway!